# Trouble retrieving random object from "deck" of card objects

Tags: oop, random

My issue is this : When I'm drawing a random card from the deck i've instantiated the returns are sometimes correct(i.e. KING_CLUBS) but sometimes I get a weird one (i.e. SEVEN_). This is odd because when the decks are instantiated, I added a print line statement in the Deck constructor to see if the  ID's were being added correctly. Every time without fail the card id's are correct.

The println in Blackjack's hitUser() method was to check the ID of the card being drawn. Sometimes it's correct other times it's not. Can anyone tell me what's happening and why?

Runnable relevant code below

My Card Class:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Card {
    //cardValues[] represents the tangible values attached to the card faces(ACE, ONE, TWO, THREE, ..., KING)
    private final static int cardValues[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
    private final static String cardIDs[] = {"ACE_", "TWO_", "THREE_", "FOUR_", "FIVE_", "SIX_", "SEVEN_", "EIGHT_", "NINE_", "TEN_", "JACK_", "QUEEN_", "KING_"};
    private int value;

    //Name of the card, i.e. "ACE";
    private String cardID;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param v - card value(I.e. 1 for Ace or 13 for King)
     */
    public Card(int v){
        setValue(v);
        setCardID(v);
    }

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param v - card value(I.e. 1 for Ace or 13 for King)
     * @param id - a manually set ID for the card(used for 'illegal' card instantiation)
     */
    public Card(int v, String id){
        setValue(v);
        setCardID(id);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the card ID
     * @return - the card ID of the respective card
     */
    public String getCardID(){
        return cardID;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the card value
     * @return - the number value of the respective card
     */
    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Setter method for card value
     * @param v - value
     */
    public void setValue(int v){
        //Checks to see if v is a valid cardValue
        if(v >= 1 && v <= 13){
            value = v;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 'legal' setter method for card ID
     * @param v - number value of the card
     */
    public void setCardID(int v){
        //Checks to see if v is a valid cardValue
        if(v >= 1 && v <= 13){
            cardID = cardIDs[v - 1];
        }
    }

    /**
     * 'illegal' setter method for card ID
     * @param id - String value of the card ID
     */
    public void setCardID(String id){
        cardID = id;
    }

    public String getIcon(){
        return "blackjack/" + this.getCardID() + ".png";
    }
```

My Deck Class:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Deck {
    private int numCards;
    private String cardSuits[] = {"SPADES", "HEARTS", "DIAMONDS", "CLUBS"};
    private static ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    public static JLabel[] cardIcons = new JLabel[52];
    public static int dealerHand, playerHand;



     /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public Deck(){

        //Will keep track of the index of the 52 cards created
        int counter = 0;

        for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
            String suit = cardSuits[y];
                for(int z = 1; z < 14; z++){
                    //Adds a new card and initializes it with its number value
                    cards.add(new Card(z));

                    //Replaces the card ID with a new ID containing the card suit (i.e. SPADES)
                    if(cards.get(counter).getCardID().indexOf("_") == cards.get(counter).getCardID().length() - 1){
                        String newID = cards.get(counter).getCardID() + suit;
                        cards.get(counter).setCardID(newID);
                        System.out.println(newID);
                        counter++;
                    } else {

                    }
                    }
            }
    }

    /**
     * Removes a card from the deck - gets rid of the object in the array of cards once it has been drawn
     * @param id - the card to be removed
     */
    public void removeCard(String id){
        for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){

            if(cards.get(i).getCardID().equalsIgnoreCase(id)){
                cards.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the object of the card within a deck
     * @param c - the index of the card within the deck
     * @return the card object
     */
    public Card getCard(int c){
        return cards.get(c);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a random card from the array of cards in the deck
     * @return - a random card object
     */
    public Card getRandomCard(){
        Random r = new Random();
        int index = r.nextInt(cards.size());

        return cards.get(index);
    }

    /**
     * Resets the deck to its original, 'perfect' order
     */
    public void reset(){
        for(int x = 0; x<cards.size(); x++){
            cards.remove(x);
        }

        //Will keep track of the index of the 52 cards created
        int counter = 0;

        for(int y = 0; y < 4; y++){
            String suit = cardSuits[y];

            for(int z = 0; z < 13; z++){
                //Adds a new card and initializes it with its number value
                cards.add(new Card(z));

                //Replaces the card ID with a new ID containing the card suit (i.e. SPADES)
                String newID = cards.get(counter).getCardID() + suit;
                cards.get(counter).setCardID(newID);

                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Blackjack Class:

```
import javax.swing.*;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

/**
 * This class provides all of the functionality of the blackjack game
 * @author Mohamed Amadou
 *
 */
public class Blackjack extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public MigLayout mig = new MigLayout("insets 0");
    public Deck bjDeckHouse = new Deck(), bjDeckUser = new Deck();
    public int dealerOffset = 65, userOffset = 65, houseHand = 0, 
    public final int MAX_BET = 100000;
    public JPanel bj = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0")), blackjack = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0"));
    public JButton hit;

    public Blackjack(){

        buildUI();
        mig.layoutContainer(bj);

        setSize(780, 700);
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(mig);
        setTitle("Blackjack");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void buildUI(){
        getContentPane().add(bj);
        bj.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        hit = new JButton("Hit");
        hit.addActionListener(this);
        bj.add(hit, "pos 570px 285px");


    }

    public void hitUser(int hand){
        JPanel test = new JPanel(new MigLayout("insets 0"));
        JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
        testFrame.add(test);

        Card hitCard = bjDeckUser.getRandomCard();
        hand += hitCard.getValue();

        String position = "pos "+ userOffset + "px" + " 580px";



        System.out.println(hitCard.getCardID());
        bjDeckUser.removeCard(hitCard.getCardID());
        turns++;
        checkBust(hand);

        testFrame.setSize(400, 400);
        testFrame.setResizable(false);
        testFrame.setLayout(mig);
        testFrame.setTitle("Blackjack Rules");
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        testFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if(e.getSource() == hit){
            hitUser(userHand);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in `reset()`:

```java
    for(int x = 0; x<cards.size(); x++){
        cards.remove(x);
    }
```

This actually does not remove all items (just play it through), you should use `cards.clear()`. Since the deck is then not empty, and you add another 52 cards, the deck will be incorrect. Additionally you will get weird names, probably also SEVEN_CLUBS_SPADES and similar.

Also, your code is a little bit confusing. Suite should be an attribute of a Card, not of a Deck. Cards should be immutable (maybe enums depending on usage). You have 2 initialization code snippets (you should have 1). GUI code in your "business model". Just a few ideas to clean up :)